# How can I use "css sprites" in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an image with multiple icons, and I have the position and the size of the icon that I want to show.

The question is, how can I show just part of an image in a `UIImageView` so I can show only the icon that I want to?

Is it possible to show the icon correctly in 1x, 2x, and 3x, even if the image gets a bit pixelated?

Comment: I don't think you can position it to make sure the correct image is displayed. Why not split the image into image_1, image_2 ... image_n?

Comment: I have the top left coordinate and the size of the icon to be shown. Cutting the image was my first solution, but the icons are in constant change and I don't have control over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crop a part of the image and create a new `UIImage` from it with `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`:

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height); //Calculate the rect you'd like to show
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, cropRect);
UIImage* outImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:originalImage.scale orientation:originalImage.imageOrientation]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```